# Making the transition from cocoapods to Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

Can't seem to find any tutorials/articles about making the transition from cocoapods to Swift Package Manager. How should that be done?

Strangely, I don't even have `Swift Package Manager` menu item inside `File` tab. It is an existing project with `cocoapods`. Xcode is Version 10.2.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift Package Manager is first integrated with Xcode in Xcode 11.

Are you an app developer or a library developer?

If you're an app developer, you should check if the CocoaPods that you use have a Swift Package Manager configuration.

If you're a library provider, you need to implement the CocoaPods podspec as a Swift Package Manager `Package.swift`.

Here's an example of the status of Firebase's migration to Swift Package Manager - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3136#issuecomment-509832654